# What is the best way to declare persistent variables in a DLL with C++

Tags: c++, dll

I am writing a DLL to implement a controller for some simulation software and I need some data to persist across calls to the DLL from the simulation process, what is the best practice to declare this persistent data? The options I can think of is just using a global variables(seems like a bad Idea), or wrap them in a namespace or class/struct(better idea?), is there another better option?
I can't change anything in the code that calls the DLL so storing the data there is not an option.

e.g

```
//option 1
double persistent1 = 0;
int persistent2 = 0;

//option 2
namespace MyDLL
{
    double persistent1 = 0;
    int persistent2 = 0;
}

//option 3
class MyDLL
{
    double persistent1 = 0;
    int persistent2 = 0;
};

MyDLL myDll = MyDLL();

void FOO_API __cdecl CALL(double* data)
{
    //do something to persistent1 and persistent2 with data.
}
```

Comment: Putting the variables inside a namespace does not mean they are not global.  The namespace you show is still global.  Namespaces merely avoid naming conflicts during compiling, they don't dicate WHERE variables are allocated in memory.

Comment: Depends on the quantity of persistent data.  For a little quantity, the DLL could use a binary file, or some other data format (like JSON).  For bigger quantities of data, the DLL could use a small database or a large database.  There are also other places a DLL can store data, for example, on Windows, the DLL could use the Registry.

Comment: What do you mean by "across calls"?  Do you mean you want to share this data between two different processes that are using your DLL?  For that, you'd need to use shared memory or similar.  If you only want to manipulate this data between calls made to your DLL within the current process, well then Windows provides the attach/detach mechanism already when a process loads a DLL.  If you want to persist information outside of your DLL being loaded, then there's registry / files.  You really must clarify your requirements, beacuse it's very unclear right now.

Comment: Unrelated: I suggest a simplification: `MyDLL myDll = MyDLL();` is nicer as `MyDLL myDll;`

Comment: You could use the ancient art of storing data into the executable.  In your executable, reserve a code section of the appropriate size.  Find the offset of this data section in the executable; read and write to this offset.  Be aware that some OSes will try to prevent you from modifying an executable.  Virus checkers (and similar utilities) will try to prevent your code from doing this or alert the User of a malicious program (yours).

Comment: @paddy "*Windows provides the attach/detach message already within a DLL*" - I don't see how that is relevant to this issue. As long as the DLL remains loaded, variables can be freely stored in the DLL's memory and accessed across function calls. You don't need the attach/detach notifications for that. And you certainly should NOT be trying to save/load data to/from persistent storage (file, Registry, etc) from inside of those notifications, that is likely to deadlock the DLL Loader.

Comment: Finally, you could check your platform to see if it has any programmable devices that can store data.  This is definitely not standard.  Store your data in these devices by programming them.  For example a Flash Memory device may have some room and can be programmed (provided the OS doesn't block your accesses).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews an extension of your idea, that won't trigger virus checkers - simply have the EXE allocate memory at runtime and pass a pointer to it into the DLL (or, have the DLL allocate the memory and return the pointer to the EXE). The DLL can then store data in that memory. The EXE could pass that pointer to each function call so the DLL can maintain state data as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I would prefer to allocate the memory in the executable and hand a pointer to the DLL unfortunately I did not write the executable and have no access to the code. Is there a way of getting access externally, such as taking a data value and reusing its memory to store a pointer to some dynamically allocated memory, this seems more problematic than the global in this context.
Writing the data to a file is out since the overhead of opening and closing a file on each call to the function would be excessively slow for the application.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1 is bad, obviously.

Option 2 is not much better.

Option 3 gives you a bit more control over integrity of your data, if you provide getters and setters. They can incorporate locking for synchronizing access from multiple threads.

Option 4 - implement a singleton, so you don't accidentally create multiple instances of `MyDLL`

Comment: Thanks for the help a singleton pattern might be the go, seems the best of a bad bunch of options